# How do I instantiate a fake CGImageRef object?

Tags: ios, swift

```
    var img         : CGImageRef
    do {
         img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    let frameImg    : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: img)
    return frameImg
```

The error I get from the 'let frameImg' line:

```
Variable 'img' used before being initialized
```

So I think I need to initialize the 'img' object before the do brackets. What is the easiest way to do this?

There doesn't seem to be a simple, easy-to-use constructor for the CGImageRef object in the Apple documentation.

Have I designed this code completely wrong?

Comment: Make `img` an optional and check that is was set properly before using it (when assigning it to the `UIImage frameImg`)

Comment: Compiler notifies you that `img` will be used before initialization in case `copyCGImageAtTime` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
do {
    var img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
    let frameImg: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: img)
    return frameImg
} catch {
    fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    // it's up to you how to handle error; you can crash the app or return some other CGImageRef
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want the image to be if `copyCGImageAtTime` throws an error. I'll assume you want a transparent image.

```
func frameImage(atTime time: CMTime) -> UIImage {
    var transparentSinglePixelImage: CGImage {
        let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, 1, 1, 8, 4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue)
        return CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)!
    }

    var cgImage: CGImage?
    do {
        cgImage = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return UIImage(CGImage: cgImage ?? transparentSinglePixelImage)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix:

```
    var img         : CGImageRef?
    do {
         img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    let frameImg    : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: img!)
    return frameImg
```

Notice the '?' to make the variable optional

Comment: This will crash in case copyCGImageAtTime fails.